# How to use OTBI data model in Visual Builder Studio?

Tags: oracle-fusion-apps

How can I use an data model from Oracle Transactional Business Intelligence(OTBI) in Visual Builder Studio, from Oracle too?
I want to show the data model as a table in visual builder.
I'm trying to use OCI to do the integration but I don't know if I'm on the right track.